# Setting IIS Application VirtualDirectory physicalpath

Tags: iis

I have a .bat file with the following line that runs appcmd to install the sites contained in sites.xml

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd add site /in < .\sites.xml
```

sites.xml contains the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<appcmd>

<SITE SITE.NAME="Default Web Site" SITE.ID="1" bindings="http/*:80:,net.tcp/808:*,net.pipe/*,net.msmq/localhost,msmq.formatname/localhost,https/*:443:" state="Started">

    <site name="Default Web Site" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">

        <bindings>

            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:" />

            <binding protocol="net.tcp" bindingInformation="808:*" />

            <binding protocol="net.pipe" bindingInformation="*" />

            <binding protocol="net.msmq" bindingInformation="localhost" />

            <binding protocol="msmq.formatname" bindingInformation="localhost" />

            <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:" />

        </bindings>

        <limits />

        <logFile />

        <traceFailedRequestsLogging />

        <applicationDefaults />

        <virtualDirectoryDefaults />

        <application path="/">

            <virtualDirectoryDefaults />

            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot" />

        </application>

         <application path="/MyWebsite" applicationPool="MyWebsite">

            <virtualDirectoryDefaults />

            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\Projects\MySolution\DEV\Source\MyWebsite" />

        </application>

    </site>

</SITE>

</appcmd>
```

I need to make part of the virtualdirectory physicalpath `D:\Projects\MySolution`  be whatever the currentdirectory is.

Is there any variable that I can insert in `sites.xml` to make that happen?

Comment: I don't think you actually have a .bat file "executing" a XML one. The content you posted seems related to an ApplicationHost.config file. Please refine your question.

Comment: @LittleSweetSeas - have edited the question.  Should be clearer now.  Thanks